# Custom rounded UIView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I'm facing the task to make a custom UIView for the first time, it should look something like this:

[image]

I've tried playing around with a UIBezierPath, but I only managed to make a circle which I don't want. Any suggestions on how to make the above?

Comment: UIBezierPath could be the way, but what did you do exactly?

Comment: The final expectation is to make something like the image? Didn't I make that clear? I'm pretty much stuck on how to.

Comment: `UIBezierPath` with custom path is a solution here.

Comment: There is a good example about `UIBezierPath` in the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/3186/uibezierpath/13624/designing-and-drawing-a-bezier-path#t=201610261524181893454)